# confusing routes on cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes

Consider two routes:

Router A:

```
Router::connect('/site', array('prefix' => 'site', 'controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Router B:

```
Router::connect('/:prefix/usuario/:action', array('controller' => 'usuarios'));
```

This link, //localhost/site/usuario/enderecos, works on router A with the prefix but do not execute the controller home and neither the action index. It does work with the route B and the controller usuarios is called.
This link, //localhost/site/usuario/endereco/156 works the same as the link above with route A, but does not work with route B. So it throws a 404 NOT FOUND.
If I put a /* at the end of Route B, it works.

My questions:

1) why the links work with the route A for any link that starts with the /site but the second link didn't with the Route B.
2) If I put a /* at the end of Route A, then all links with /site starts asking for a home controller and a site_index action. Why?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

prefix generally works for `admin` routeing... So, if your url ends with '`site`' (which is on your 'A') then it will map to `site_index` action on `HomesController`.

Read more on prefix routeing-[documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)